# Grounding a chassis with two prong plug

Tags: audio, ground, preamp, wall-wart, chassis

So I kinda shot myself in the foot by purchasing a two prong wall wart to power an audio preamplifier that I designed. I forgot to consider the fact that I should ground my chassis to the earth connection via a three prong AC plug. Does anyone know a way I can ground my chassis while still using the two prong wall wart? I was considering modifying the wall wart by adding an additional discrete prong on top of it that would plug into the earth connection of an outlet. If you think that I can get away with leaving my chassis floating, please let me know as well. Thanks.

Comment: Lots of audio equipment nowadays has no ground connection and works fine without it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the connecting the ground of your chassis to the earth?

Comment: It would be fairly normal to ground the power amp to AC, and ground the preamp via the audio cables to the power amp.

Comment: I doubt it with the wall wart but just to check: is this a vacuum tube preamp?  I.e.: do you have 230V plate supply running around in there?

Comment: No, the entire thing is op amp based since I am on a budget for class. No vacuum tubes, no isolation transformers, nada.  And the purpose (for D Duck) of connecting chassis to the earth connection is so that there is a non-audio return path for any induced noise and for electrical safety

Answer (score 1):

wanted to let you know that I found a solution. I cracked open the wall wart and took out the circuit. I took an AC plug and wired the live and neutral together and then used the earth connection for the chassis. Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0):

A ring terminal to the faceplate mounting screw on the outlet and connected to a convenient screw on the chassis is probably the easiest and safest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to purchase a power supply with a ground terminal. Modifying a wall wart could potentially make it unsafe. It's really up to the application to see if it needs grounding, many applications don't need it. Audio does not need a DC ground and in many cases a ground usually makes ground loops. Usually chassis ground is for safety reasons. In the event of a fault of AC mains, current returns to ground instead of shocking someone.

If you really do need a ground, you could add one with a second cable for prototyping purposes. There are cables available (from amazon) that have only a ground clip and 3 prongs.